# How to set a default value for a jquery autocomplete box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How would you set a default value for an autocomplete box from the set values using an id?

The values come from the db.

Essentially what I want is the same as a normal select in html where you can specifcally say this option selected (selected=selected)

I'm new to this whole jquery thing and have seen a similar topic but can't seem to get it to work

Heres my code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
    <input id="birds"  />
</div>
```

So when the page loads I want it to have selected a value from my source eg: robin

This is code from the demo I'm try to manipulate to work the way I want to

Answer (score 2):

I would just set the `input`'s value to the default value you'd like:

```
<input value="robin" id="birds" />
```

Comment: With value attribute you will not be able to modify the value after initialization

Comment: @MeysamFeghhi This is simply not true. You can always change the value using `.value` or jQuery's `.val(...)`.

Comment: I meant the user cannot change it via the field in the browser

Comment: @MeysamFeghhi: I don't think that's true either: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/nqf8qg9j/. Can you post an example of what you're describing?